# Get specific string from string, starting with pattern

Tags: php, string-matching

I receive a string like this:

```
class1 fa-dollar class2 class3
```

Now, i need to check this string for a string/word containing `fa-*`. How can I manage that with PHP?

Wordwise as code

```
if(custom_strpos($myReceivedString, 'fa-')) {
    echo $faStringOnly;
    // output: 'fa-dollar'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Explode, loop, and substring. What do you need to happen when there is more than one `fa-`?

Comment: What do you mean by check? If all you need to do is the actual check then `strpos($string, "fa-") !== false` would be enough.

Comment: @DirkScholten I don't know what `fa-*` comes out at the end. I know I have to search for the pattern `fa-` but have to receive the full string (like `fa-dollar` in this example above)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus well looping is an option, create a function and make it like that, but there should be maybe something easier (like regex)? But thanks, at least I have a solution for now.

Comment: `preg_match` with `/(fa-[^\s]*)/` or `explode` and `preg_grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with two code examples:

```
$example = "class1 fa-dollar class2 class3";
if (preg_match_all('/(fa-\w+)/', $example, $matches)) {
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    print $match . "\n";
  }
}

$moreThan1 = "class1 fa-dollar class2 fa-other class3";
if (preg_match_all('/(fa-\w+)/', $example, $matches)) {
  foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    print $match . "\n";
  }
}
```

First example is your example. We're using `preg_match_all` to match all instances. In your example, there is only one.  The regular expression match is `/fa-\w+/` which says "this match begins with `fa-` and then has 1 or more word-based characters. (I made this assumption based on `fa-dollar` which I'm assuming are classes from Font Awesome.

The found matches are put into `$matches` and the exmaple code shows how you can loop through them.

To show that this works with more than one match, you can see the second example.